# Do Wings of Liberty decisions have any effect in Heart of the Swarm?

Tags: starcraft-2

Do any of the player's decisions made during the Wings of Liberty campaign, such as choice of which mission to follow or which upgrade to unlock have any effect on the Heart of the Swarm campaign?